# How to simulate a specific Internet connection?

Tags: android, simulation

I have an application that uses the internet to do many operations. Occasionally the application does not work correctly and apparently it is because of a bad or slow internet connection. The point is that I need to simulate that particular scenario in order to provide a good solution to that problem.

I tried to search about anything that would allow that capability, or if it is something not possible, I was hoping to find something that would so specify it but did not succeed.

The closest thing to this capability I found is to limit the connection via router or something similar, but I need something that can limit the internet connection no matter what type of device my device is using. When I say limit the connection I mean for example if my upload speed is 100Mb/s limit it to 50.

Comment: Try routing your device through a Charles proxy or similar software.  https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: You can also use an emulator. On the emulator you can change the setting to simulate weak internet connection. Also 50Mb/s is quite fast. Slow would be 2Mb/s or even lower depending on what is your app trying to load.